# How to get each pixel value of raster, and compare with another image using gdal/python/bash/freeware?

Tags: raster

I need to grab every pixel value of an raster image (.tif, single band, with pixel value as elevation value) and compare it with another image to see if the pixel values are identical or not. Tried gdalcompare.py, but this only gives generic differences such as file name, file type, file size etc.

I only have access to freeware, would be awesome to find out a way how to do this, as my google searches have been futile

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use Imagemagick's [`compare` tool](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/compare.php) for this. (If the usage examples on that page aren't enough, there's [more here](https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compare/).)

For example, this command would compare `image1.tiff` and `image2.tiff`, output the number of differing pixels ([other metrics are available too](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#metric)) to the console and write a difference map to `differing_pixels.tiff`.

```
compare -metric AE image1.tiff image2.tiff differing_pixels.tiff
```

Comment: Hi AKX, thank you for the heads up, is it possible to get the actual pixel values where there is a difference, rather than the absolute error count? Cheers and many thanks Rose

Comment: Tried this method anyway, this error message same up, not sure what it is means sorry. `rose@Thinkpad:~$ compare -metric AE /media/rose/RoseUSB/PeteOverHere/DSM_BQ25_2015_1000_1734.tif /media/rose/RoseUSB/PeteOverHere/DEM_BQ25_2015_1000_1734.tif differing_pixels.tiff
compare: no decode delegate for this image format TIFF @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/554.
rose@Thinkpad:~$ `

Comment: That looks like ImageMagick doesn't have TIFF support. How did you install ImageMagick?

Comment: You'll probably need to add a `--with-libtiff` or similar flag when configuring it, then... Which platform (OS, distro, version) is this on?